# Number of ways to partition a set of balls of two colors into k urns

Tags: combinatorics

A **set of $n_1$ green and $n_2$ red balls**, where $n_1 + n_2 = n$, is to be **partitioned into $k$ urns**. Both the balls and the urns are **indistinguishable** (unlabeled). **How many ways** to do the partitioning?

**Example:**
2 red balls, 2 green balls and 2 urns give the following **5** partitions: 
{RRGG, -}
{RRG, G}
{RGG, R}
{RG, RG}
{RR, GG}

It seems like some variant of the Integer Partition problem, but I couldn't find any online resources that discuss it. I may be wrong though.. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: rgg, g should be rgg, r.

Comment: fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number with $k$ infinite ($k\ge n$ will suffice) is tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A054225). An interesting special case is that in which $n_1=n_2$; that's tabulated [here](https://oeis.org/A002774). At those pages you'll find links to other special cases, references to the literature, formulas, and so on.

If you want a formula for $F(n_1,n_2,k)$, you may be asking for too much.

Comment: Could you please direct me to any references that have any discussion of the case with $k$ < $n$?

Comment: No, but here's a method that might work. Find a formula for $F(n_1,n_2,2)$ --- I don't think that's too hard --- then look it up at the OEIS. Maybe you can even find a formula for $F(n_1,n_2,3)$, or at least calculate a few values of $F(m,m,3)$, and look them up. Did you follow up on all the references and links at the URLs I gave? Maybe some of them discuss the problem.

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: Sorry. Have been so busy recently. I am (trying) to read through the references.. not as easy as I expected though :-).